# Substituir saída de um comando por uma mensagem customizada

Tags: bash, shell-script

Estou criando um script onde no final do mesmo eu executo um comando que exibe uma saída muito grande de informações. É possível substituir essa saída? Ou seja, ao invés dele mostrar a saída padrão mostrar apenas uma mensagem ex: **Conectado.** ?

O comando a executar seria:

```
sudo openvpn --config srvproxy-udp-1194-config.ovpn
```

A saída dele é assim normalmente:

> Thu Sep 21 09:48:48 2017 WARNING: file 'srvproxy-udp-1194-tls.key' is
>   group or others accessible Thu Sep 21 09:48:48 2017 OpenVPN 2.4.0
>   x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11]
>   [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Jun 22 2017 Thu Sep 21 09:48:48 2017
>   library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016, LZO 2.08 Enter Auth
>   Username: xxxxxx Enter Auth Password: ******* Thu Sep 21 09:48:54 2017
>   TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address:
>   [AF_INET]200.210.150.105:1194 Thu Sep 21 09:48:54 2017 UDP link local
>   (bound): [AF_INET][undef]:0 Thu Sep 21 09:48:54 2017 UDP link remote:
>   [AF_INET]200.210.150.105:1194 Thu Sep 21 09:48:54 2017 WARNING: this
>   configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache
>   option to prevent this Thu Sep 21 09:48:54 2017 [www.xxxxxxx.com.br]
>   Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]200.210.150.105:1194 Thu Sep
>   21 09:48:55 2017 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened Thu Sep 21 09:48:55 2017
>   do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0 Thu Sep 21 09:48:55 2017
>   /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500 Thu Sep 21 09:48:55 2017
>   /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 172.8.0.6 peer 172.8.0.5 Thu Sep 21
>   09:48:55 2017 Initialization Sequence Completed

Comment: Qual o comando executado?

Comment: @ZumodeVidrio editada a pergunta

Comment: Como é que você sabe se finalmente foi conectado ou não?

Answer (score 2):

Já tentou:

```
sudo openvpn --config srvproxy-udp-1194-config.ovpn > /dev/null && echo "Conectado" || echo "Ops, tem algo errado"
```

?

Comment: O que eu não gosto no curto-circuito é a possibilidade do comando depois do `&&` dar errado, então ele iria para o comando do `||` (não conheço caso de falha do `echo`, mas eu tenho neurose com isso); mas eu faria desse mesmo modo. Só atenção que talvez seja necessário jogar a saída de erro para `/dev/null` também

Comment: Nesse caso adicionando um exit 0 no comando após o && talvez funcione, exemplo:

service mysql status > /dev/null && (echo "UP"; exit 0) || (c=$?; echo "DOWN"; (exit $c))

Comment: Poderia usar o `true` também, o comando garantido a retornar com sucesso

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar um if no seu script, descartando a saída do comando:

```
#!/bin/bash

if openvpn --config srvproxy-udp-1194-config.ovpn >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
        echo "Conectado"
else
        echo "Não conectado"
fi
```

Caso precise guardar a saída, você pode redirecioná-la para um log:
`if openvpn --config srvproxy-udp-1194-config.ovpn > /tmp/openvpn.log ; then`

Comment: O caminho é por aí, só estou tentando ajustar pra funcionar este if chamando o comando.

Comment: @Douglas Qual parte não funcionou? O snippet que eu mandei utiliza o mesmo comando do post original.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer desta forma:

Vamos usar como exemplo o comando ls

```
ls > saida.txt
```

ele vai jogar toda a saída para dentro do arquivo saida.txt e não vai mostrar nada na tela, você pode analisar o resultado no arquivo saida.txt e então manda a mensagem para o usuário.

Comment: Não teria uma maneira mais simples ?

Comment: Depende, o que você quer fazer? Qual o comando que você quer executar?